# Comparing principal components if number of variables changes

Tags: time-series, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a database that contains daily stock returns of more than a thousand stocks for many decades. I would like to achieve the following goals:

1. Construct a **time-varying** measure of co-movement (or common component) of stock returns.
2. Compare the evolution of this measure over time, and later relate it to other variables.

The main idea is to see whether *the importance of the common component of stock returns systematically varies over the business cycle*.

My first idea was to run a PCA in each quarter, save the the share of explained variance by the first principal component, and then this quarterly time series of explained variance would be the measure of co-movement over time. The problem, however, is that the number of variables for which I run the PCA is not constant over time. In the early part of the sample I have, say, 200 stocks and in the more recent part, say, 1000. I assume it doesn't make sense to compare the explained variance by PC1 if the number of variables is different over time.

Is there any measure that can be compared if the number of variables changes over time?

Comment: You're asking how a certain task can be accomplished, and I don't think that particular task can.  But if you describe further what end result you want to achieve, or what range of results, someone should have useful advice for you.

Comment: Maybe this example helps: imagine that I observe the daily return of 10 stocks over 2 years. My hypothesis is that in the first year investors didn't distinguish much between these companies, but in the second year they started to distinguish them. If this is true, I should see that in Year 1 the returns tend to move together very strongly, while in Year 2 we expect more idiosyncratic movements. In other words, the common component (say PC1) should explain much more variance in Year 1 than in Year 2. Now I want something similar, but the universe of stocks in the sample can change over time.

Comment: You rise a good question: how to compare eigenvalues (in particularly, the extent of dominance of the 1st one) of correlation/covariance matrices of different size. Or, put another way, what are good approaches to standardize eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you, @ttnphns. I couldn't describe my problem in mathematical/statistical terms, but this is exactly what I am after. Some sort of normalization which takes into account the dimension of the problem. (Something like an adjusted R-squared in regression analysis.) Maybe this makes my question more interesting to the stats guys:)

Comment: A challenging question, for sure. My immediate concerns are, first, why and how you came up with the two, stated questions. What are you hoping to learn? In other words, what is your primary objective in obtaining answers to them? You need to tell us more about what you're doing and why. Next, why choose an approach (PCA) which is gaussian, linear, static and classically multivariate? Especially given that it is well known that stock returns do *not* fit gaussian, linear assumptions?